# Displaying records from a table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for the newbie question, but I am working on my first PHP script and I can't seem to make it work. I just want to display the records from a single MySQL table. I have been trying to do this for ages and it is not displaying anything except the first two echo statements, before it is supposed to pull out the data.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
  mysql_connect("localhost", "me", "mypass") or die(mysql_error());
  echo "Connection to the server was successful!<br/>";

  mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
  echo "Database was selected!<br/>";

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Customer");

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo "ID: ".$row['customer_id'].", Name:".$row['customer_name']
  ."<br/>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Maybe the query is getting an error. Add `or die(mysql_error())` to the end of the `mysql_query()` line.

Comment: Or maybe there's nothing in the Customer table.

Comment: If you're new, you should learn good habits off the bat. Don't use the obsolete `mysql_XXX` functions, learn `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Comment: I did it, and you're right--it says "table test.Customer doesn't exist." I am trying to figure out what is wrong . . .

Comment: On Linux, table names are case-sensitive. So if the table is named `CUSTOMER` or `customer`, `Customer` won't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Aha! The database name was test1, not test. I can't believe I missed that. I just kept looking for syntax errors. Thank you very much, really.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo mysql_num_rows($result);
```

to know the number of rows returned by your query.

Comment: That won't work since he's getting an error from the query; see the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the `table` or the `database` you are trying to connect doesnt exits.

As @barmar suggests table names are case sensitive..

Please make sure that you are using the correct database and table ..THanx